# WinAppDriver code to access the existing application controls

Tags: c#, .net, selenium-webdriver, appium, winappdriver

I'm new to `winappdriver` and writing an automation code using `NUnit`, `Appium` and `winappdriver` in `C#`.

I have a question regarding the situation. There is a running application called **"sample.exe"** that is currently retrieving live readings from a sensor on my desktop. I need to develop separate code to identify and halt the execution of this running application in order to stop the reading. Below is the code I have written to launch the application and retrieve the readings.

**The Code:**

```
namespace SampleWinAppDriver
{

public class DriverFactory
{
    public WindowsDriver<WindowsElement> driver;

    public WindowsDriver<WindowsElement> InitializeDriver()
    {
        AppiumOptions cap = new AppiumOptions();
        cap.AddAdditionalCapability("app", "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\DC\\Sample\\Sample.exe");
        driver = new WindowsDriver<WindowsElement>(new Uri("http://127.0.0.1:4723/"), cap);
        if (driver == null)
        {

            Console.WriteLine("App not started");
            return null;
        }
        else
            return driver;

    }
  }
}
```

I require a distinct program to locate this application and terminate (click the stop button) its execution.

I have tried with the following code. But I couldn't get the object of the existing windows handle to access the buttons in my application.

```
Process[] procesos = Process.GetProcessesByName("sample");
```